# Insert class into element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The URL is http://csidb.com/web-online-marketing/creative-portfolio/

I have done some research on how to insert a class into an element using jQuery. My element (h1) currently has no classes. The code that I wrote based on my research is:

```
<script>
$( "h1" ).addClass( "otherclass" );
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
<script>
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
d.className = "otherclass";
</script>
```

And I tried wrapping those snippets with `$(document).ready(function() { });`

The issue is is that it is not adding that class to h1 tags. I'm using a pre developed WordPress theme so I'd prefer not to touch the parent theme (I have a child theme in place). I have control over the header.

I would include my code in a fiddle but there are a lot of moving parts. I think it might be easier to use inspect element or view the source code. If this is incorrect, let me know and I'll try to make a fiddle.

I'm not -that- familiar with JS so I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this.

Edit: is there a way to do this without Javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work fine-- not sure what issue you're having: http://jsfiddle.net/x6m216rm/1/

Comment: Try `jQuery("h1").addClass("otherclass");`

Comment: Hi Chad, I tested it in jsfiddle and it worked too. I think something else in the code is affecting it, which is why I suggested looking at the source code instead of a simple jsfiddle I could have made :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code . Even i saw the error in console. Your code is correct to add a class. But for this you have to add a jquery file first.

Add this above your code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "h1" ).addClass( "otherclass" );
</script>
```

You are using jquery but you have not included it in your code. Thats why in console you are getting this error "undefined is not a function". Basically it refers to the jquery selector i.e "$". Add this online library first to your code or you can also download this library and keep it on your local and then add it as a reference.

Comment: I checked to see if the jquery library was included. Is this not it then? <script type='text/javascript' src='http://csidb.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>

Comment: But the error you are getting is about jquery not included. Or one reason could also be there that you have included more than one jquery files. Which sometimes create the conflicts. Try calling it in header of the page and only once.

Comment: Just try to remove the error which you are getting in the console . Move your jquery file on the top of all jquery plugins. as if in head tag. You will surely got to know where the actual problem is .

Comment: I just included the library link you put in your original answer and also tried replacing it with the most recent library and both of them didn't work :(

Comment: I did include the library in the header

Comment: I still can see two errors in your console . Try to remove that which will automatically tell you the reason of not working code. Comment the hash change script js which is creating the error. Then call your jquery js on the top of every js . its in header but still one or two js files are above it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72789/discussion-between-rohit-arora-and-tara).

Answer (score 0):

addClass method is not available for older versions of jquery. You can rather use

```
$("h1").attr("class", "otherclass");
```

And regarding the pure JS code, the getElementsByTagName() returns a list. Hence you need to access the first element of it to make it work.

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
d[0].className = "otherclass";
```

EDIT: addClass(function) is added later in jquery1.4. My fault. You might have forgot to inlcude the jquery instead.

Comment: I tried inputting your second code and it didn't seem to work. Could it be that I referred to jquery 1.11 instead of the most recent 2.1.3?

Comment: The second code does not require jquery to work. It works here http://jsfiddle.net/tckkq0dn/

Comment: I tested it in jsfiddle and it worked too. I think something else in the code is affecting it, which is why I suggested looking at the source code instead of a simple jsfiddle I could have made

Comment: i checked that link, try changing 'otherClass' to 'otherclass' in the css part and run again.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, mayank. I don't have otherclass/otherClass defined in CSS yet. I'm actually doing this because of some structured data errors Google has notified me of.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
$("h1").attr("class", "myClass");
```

Comment: this will replace previously applied class instead use .addClass('newClass');

Comment: I would normally suggest .addClass() but since the question included that and she said the tags currently had no existing classes I figured it was worth the mention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ashton. I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work.